# Why does this Power function return zero for negative exponential cases?

Tags: python, function, exponential

The function returns zero for all negative exponential cases: 
For example: `print power(2, -3)` returns 0

```
def power(int1, int2):
   if int2 == 0:
       return 1

   result = int1

   for num in range(1, int2):
       result*=int1

   if int2 > 0:
       return result

   else:
       return (1/result)
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Also if you're getting zero you should really switch to Python 3.

Comment: Python 2 with which has integer division?

Comment: You should use python3

Comment: also don't name arguments to your function a python type, as this could cause some ugly problems downstream. You should probably rename `int` to `int1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct usage:

```
def power(int1, int2):

    result = int1

    for num in range(1, abs(int2)): #Must be positive value!  use "abs()"
        result*=int1

    if int2 == 0:
        return 1

    elif int2 > 0:
        return result

    else:
        return (1/result)

print(power(2, -3)) #OUTPUT: 0.125
```

Comment: This is dodgy at best because you're using the `int` builtin name